# How to play flv file inside Ext.Window?

Tags: extjs, flv, flash

How do I play a .flv file inside Ext.Window?

Comment: I've never tried it, but it ought to work (but who knows, with flash...).  Have you tried embedding some FLV player there? What's broken about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the Media UX.

[Media UX Forum Thread](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?23983-ux.Media-.Flash-Flex-Components-2.1.2)